# Может ли работать My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile с сетевыми папками?

Tags: .net, vb.net

При попытке использовать код для скачивания файла по сети

```
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile
```

Выдает ошибку о том что не может найти часть пути, куда сохранять файл.
Путь до файла существует, но это сетевая папка, подключенная как `M:\\`
Вопрос, может ли работать DownloadFile с сетевыми папками?

Comment: в таком случае сперва надо скачать файл во временное место на физ диске а потом перенести по сети?

Comment: и при чем тут http протокол, если этот же http протокол не работает и с локальными дисками?